# PHP unset parts of a nested array

Tags: php, arrays, unset

Trying to process an array and remove a specific associative array in a larger array set. The code I have now works in removing the specific sections locally, within the for loop, but doesn't effect the original `$cursor` array.

```
foreach($cursor as $key) {

    foreach($key as $value => $k){

        if ($value == 'user'){

            unset($k['confinfo']);
        }
    }   
}
```

Is it a GLOBAL variable problem? How to unset the original variable?

Comment: Is the top level array cursor?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Iterate over the original array by reference:

```
foreach($cursor as &$key) // added &
```

It's important to note than whenever you do this, it's a *very* good idea to follow the loop with an `unset` to destroy the reference:

```
foreach($cursor as &$key) {
    // ...
}
unset($key);
```

Personally I find this a little ugly (par for the course in PHP), but this way you eliminate the risk of reusing the name `$key` later on and causing all sorts of "interesting" effects.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that the `$k` you get in the loop is not the original array that `$cursor` contains, it's just a copy that gets destroyed once the loop goes into the next round. To really remove the `confinfo` index from `$cursor` you need to start with `$cursor` and reference work your way down.

Replace

```
unset($k['confinfo']);
```

with

```
unset($cursor[$key][$value]['confinfo']);
```

It's not as short as the other answer, but it shows better what's going on and is thus easier to debug and extend later.